# socat two serial ports together

Tags: socat

I am writing a JUnit test to test my application. The application is written in Java and uses the purejavacomm library. To test the serial parser I want to setup a virtual serial port so the test can communicate with the parser. In addition to simply parsing, it also dynamically connects to the serial port when it becomes available so I do not want to use, say a `PipedInputStream`.

This library only looks for device files that start with `ttyS`, `ttyUSB`, or `ttyACM`. Because of this, I cannot do the regular (which would produce serial ports in `/dev/pts/x`):

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

I tried doing:

```
socat /dev/ttyS20 /dev/ttyS21
```

but it doesn't work. It doesn't exit, or print an error. I tried connecting to `/dev/ttyS20` with screen, but it just says, `[screen is terminating]`.

I looked at the user permissions for `ttyS20` (and 21), and they both have the group, `dialout` (user: root), which my user is in (chris).

I don't want to use anything with `sudo`, because I want the test to create the serial bindings. So I don't want to run the test as root.

Am I overlooking something with the permissions? Is there a better way to do this all together?